# How to pass string array to a @PathVariable in Java springs

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have below API to be tested. Not getting solution to pass string array to requestors. Tried with comma seperated values, values with in [] etc.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v10/{user}/alerts/alertguids/{requestors}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public String[] retrieveRunnableAlertGuidsByRequestors(@RequestParam(value = "productId") final String productId,
                                                           @PathVariable final String[] requestors)
```

Comment: Below URIs are not working:                                              "/alertguids/"+"WestClipNext,Master"+ "?productId=" + PRODUCT;     "/alertguids/"+"[WestClipNext,Master]"+ "?productId=" + PRODUCT;

Comment: Just use comma seperated values and get rid of brackets:  `/alertguids/WestClipNext,Master?productId=" + PRODUCT`

Comment: @UsermujM: No, as I said in above comment, comma seperated values won't work. It considers the whole string as single value instead considering it as multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure with @PathVariable but you can use the @RequestParam.

eg:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v10/{user}/alerts/alertguids/{requestors}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public String[] retrieveRunnableAlertGuidsByRequestors(@RequestParam(value = "productId") final String productId,
                                                           @RequestParam(value = "param[]")  final String[] requestors)
```